# Last row is overriding the all listview in master section in SAP FIORI

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am working with `SAP FIORI` setup. in that setup every thing is working fine,and I am getting data from server by using `ODATA service`. But here the problem is last record is overrides the value of all records data in my view.

*Note::* In server response getting all different records.

can any one suggest me how to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the ids of the entities which are in the entity-set you are requesting?
It sounds for me as if there is something wrong in the backend. Because even if the entities contain different data, but have the same id, you will have the problem you describe.

UI5 stores the data internally and uses the id for mapping. If you have the same id for every entity, the last data would be the one which is shown for every list entry (like in you case).